# contenteditable div append a html element and v-model it in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, contenteditable

Here is my Html code.

```
<div id="app">

  <button @click="renderHtml">clisdfsdfsdfck to appen html</button>
  <div class="flex">
      <div class="message" @input="fakeVmodel" v-html="html" contenteditable="true"></div>
      <div class="message">{{ html }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is js part

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        html: 'some text',
    },
    methods: {
        fakeVmodel: function(e){
            this.html = e.target.innerText;
        },
        renderHtml: function(){
          this.html += '<img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/853/1*FH12a2fX61aHOn39pff9vA.jpeg" alt="" width=200px>';
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, when I click the button to push a html tag(img) to my variable (html) and it works. but after typing, it will remove the tag part that was insert. Is that any way to append to html code successful in Vue?

Here is the codepen example
https://codepen.io/weretyc/pen/EwXZYL?editors=1010

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The main problem:**
The html disappears because of `this.html = e.target.innerText;`. Instead, use `this.html = e.target.innerHTML;`. `innerHTML` resolves to the full HTML content.

**Secondary Problem:**
After typing, the cursor focuses the *beginning* of the div. This is because `v-html` causes the div to update.

To solve, ensure that `v-html` only updates the div on focusout.

**Full Example**

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    html: 'some text',
  },
  methods: {
    updateHtml: function(e) {
      this.html = e.target.innerHTML;
    },
    renderHtml: function(){
      this.html += '<img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/853/1*FH12a2fX61aHOn39pff9vA.jpeg" alt="" width=200px>';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 
  <button @click="renderHtml">click to append html</button>
  <div class="flex">
      <div class="message" @focusout="updateHtml" v-html="html" contenteditable="true"></div>
      <br>
      <div class="message">{{ html }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @asemahle, do you know how to insert component into `contenteditable`, store inserted code into database and recreate inserted content to edit again later?