# Update v-html without misbehaving focus on typing VUE JS

Tags: vue.js

I need help,

**Requirement**

when the user types in an input box I want to highlight the link with blue color if any

**My Research**

when I dig into it, I realize that without using a contenteditable div it's not possible to do, also there is no v-model associated with contenteditable div I am manually updating the state.
so far I have this, courtesy- [contenteditable div append a html element and v-model it in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487619/contenteditable-div-append-a-html-element-and-v-model-it-in-vuejs#answers-header)

```
 <div id="app"><div class="flex">
          <div class="message" @input="updateHtml" v-html="html" contenteditable="true"></div>
          <br>
          <div class="message">{{ html }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <script>
    let app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        html: 'some text',
      },
      methods: {
        updateHtml: function(e) {
          this.html = e.target.innerHTML;
        },
        renderHtml: function(){
          this.html += '<img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/853/1*FH12a2fX61aHOn39pff9vA.jpeg" alt="" width=200px>';
        }
      }
    });</script>
```

**Issue**

every time user types something, the focus is misbehaving which is strange to me, I want v-html to update along with user types `@keyup,@keydown` also have the same behavior.it works ok on `@blur @focusout` events, but that's not what I want

Appreciate Help.Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Posting the answer so that may help other developers. v-HTML doesn't do all the trick. You’ll need to store the cursor position so it can be restored properly each time the content updates as well as parse the content so that it renders as expected. Here is the example

**HTML**

```
<p>
An example of live syntax highlighting in a content-editable element. The hard part is storing and restoring selection after changing the DOM to account for highlighting.
<p>
    
<div contentEditable='true' id='editor'>
Edit text here. Try some words like bold and red
</div>

<p>
Just a demo trivial syntax highlighter, should work with any syntax highlighting you want to implement.
</p>
```

**JS**

```
const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
const selectionOutput = document.getElementById('selection');

function getTextSegments(element) {
    const textSegments = [];
    Array.from(element.childNodes).forEach((node) => {
        switch(node.nodeType) {
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                textSegments.push({text: node.nodeValue, node});
                break;
                
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                textSegments.splice(textSegments.length, 0, ...(getTextSegments(node)));
                break;
                
            default:
                throw new Error(`Unexpected node type: ${node.nodeType}`);
        }
    });
    return textSegments;
}

editor.addEventListener('input', updateEditor);

function updateEditor() {
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    const textSegments = getTextSegments(editor);
    const textContent = textSegments.map(({text}) => text).join('');
    let anchorIndex = null;
    let focusIndex = null;
    let currentIndex = 0;
    textSegments.forEach(({text, node}) => {
        if (node === sel.anchorNode) {
            anchorIndex = currentIndex + sel.anchorOffset;
        }
        if (node === sel.focusNode) {
            focusIndex = currentIndex + sel.focusOffset;
        }
        currentIndex += text.length;
    });
    
    editor.innerHTML = renderText(textContent);
    
    restoreSelection(anchorIndex, focusIndex);
}

function restoreSelection(absoluteAnchorIndex, absoluteFocusIndex) {
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    const textSegments = getTextSegments(editor);
    let anchorNode = editor;
    let anchorIndex = 0;
    let focusNode = editor;
    let focusIndex = 0;
    let currentIndex = 0;
    textSegments.forEach(({text, node}) => {
        const startIndexOfNode = currentIndex;
        const endIndexOfNode = startIndexOfNode + text.length;
        if (startIndexOfNode <= absoluteAnchorIndex && absoluteAnchorIndex <= endIndexOfNode) {
            anchorNode = node;
            anchorIndex = absoluteAnchorIndex - startIndexOfNode;
        }
        if (startIndexOfNode <= absoluteFocusIndex && absoluteFocusIndex <= endIndexOfNode) {
            focusNode = node;
            focusIndex = absoluteFocusIndex - startIndexOfNode;
        }
        currentIndex += text.length;
    });
    
    sel.setBaseAndExtent(anchorNode,anchorIndex,focusNode,focusIndex);
}

function renderText(text) {
    const words = text.split(/(\s+)/);
    const output = words.map((word) => {
        if (word === 'bold') {
            return `<strong>${word}</strong>`;
        }
        else if (word === 'red') {
            return `<span style='color:red'>${word}</span>`;
        }
        else {
            return word;
        }
    })
    return output.join('');
}

updateEditor();
```

Hope this helps...